# REST API design to upload multiple multipart files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am struggling to understand the concept on how to design an API. The statement given to me is

***API to create Categories(5), products(2 for each category), upload images for each product and its price.***

I am using spring to handle the REST end point . On looking at above statement , I can think of creating two separate POST requests . One to create category(ex:http://appname:port/CreateCategory). While saving the `category` entity , I would create id for each category called `categoryId`.
The post request JSON would be like this

```
{
"categoryName":"abc"
}
```

I would create other separate POST request , (ex:http://appname:port/CreateProduct)this time a multipartfile and I would associate each product with category id generated previously and save them in product table.The JSON request would look like this

```
{ 
multipart file// the uploaded image
"productName":"xyz",
"CategoryId":"123"

}
```

But the statement seems to be telling to create a single API to do all actions at once . In that case, I may have multiple multipartFiles and I have to keep track of which multipart file belongs to which product. How should I handle this scenario using SpringBoot?

Comment: Looks like the statement mention creating a product with categiry=5 and quantity =2?

Comment: @VedantKekan No,It means there are 5 categories and each one can have upto 2 products